# Concatenate two SURFPoints arrays in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, surf, matlab-cvst

Assume I have two SURFPoints arrays which stored in `surfP1` and `surfP2`. Is there any way to concatenate these two arrays together as a whole? I saw there is a function `cat` there, but I didn't find how to use it in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly right. Use `cat`.  Here's an example using an image from the image processing toolbox.  I'll use the camera man image, and also rotate it by 55 degrees.  We will detect SURF points for both images, then stack them together:

```
im = imread('cameraman.tif');
im2 = imrotate(im, 55);
surfP1 = detectSURFFeatures(im);
surfP2 = detectSURFFeatures(im2);
surfFinal = cat(2, surfP1, surfP2);
```

`points_final` will stack the two interest point structure arrays together into a single structure array.  The first parameter to `cat` is the dimension that you want to operate over to concatenate what you need.  In our case, we choose 2 as we want to concatenate horizontally.  It's very peculiar because `surfP1` and `surfP2` are both structure arrays that are column-oriented, so `N x 1` rather than `1 x N`, and so if you want to try to stack the columns together, you would think to use `cat(1,...)` but I received an error message when trying to do that, specifying that horizontal concatenation is required.  It may be due to the fact that the arrays are structures rather than numerical arrays, but I can't say for sure.

In any case, what follows the parameter 2 is all of the arrays or matrices that you want to concatenate together.  In this case, it would be the two interest point structure arrays.  Alternatively, you can also use [`vertcat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html) to do the same thing:

```
surfFinal = vertcat(surfP1, surfP2);
```

Here, using `vertcat` works to stack the columns together... for some odd reason, but it gets the job done.